# Retrieve all documents where _ids are in another collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to return all documents from the "usersessions" collection where `_id`s are in my "users" collection.

I tried the following:

```
db.usersessions.find( { "userId": { $in: (db.getCollection('users').find({},{"_id":1})) }  } )
```

which returns an error:

> Error: error: { "waitedMS" : NumberLong(0), "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "$in needs an array", "code" : 2 }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the error message [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) needs an array. You can use the [`distinct`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) to return an array of `_id` from the "users" collection. The reason is that `_id` are unique within the collection.

```js
var ids = db.getCollection('users').distinct('_id');
db.usersessions.find( { "userId": { "$in": ids } })
```